# dictionary as reference for different instances of a class

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm trying to find a solution for the following problem:
I have the class `Alert` which is created a large number of times and its instances appears as a field of type: `List<Alert>`.
one of the fields of `Alert` suppose to use a map which is a predefined dictionary (this item never changes).
how can I configure `map` so it won't have to be created with each creation of `Alert`?

meaning:

```
public class Alerts {
    private List<Alert> list;
    .
    .
    .
    public Alerts() {
        list = new ArrayList<Alert>();
        for (...) {
            Alert alert = new Alert();
            list.add(alert);
        }
    }
}

public class Alert() {
    private String str = "";
    .
    .
    .
    public Alert() {
        for (int i = 0; i < map.size; i++) {
            str += map.get(i); //map is visible and never changes for any                     
                               //instance
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `map.get[i]` is not valid syntax for a Map. What `Map` are you talking about?

Comment: I think you want a List or an array, not a Map.

Comment: no, it is '(i)', not a '[i]'

Comment: Still, you probably want a list if you're using an incremental integer index to walk the map keys.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like this `map` should be a static member of your class. You can initialize it in a static initializer block.

Comment: `final` would also be a good addition.. Just for safety :P.. +1 BTW

Answer (score 1):

You should use a static filed if all instances of the class will be using the same data. Also you can make the map unmodifiable (just to make sure you -or someone else- don't mess it up).

```
private static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

static {
    // Insert your keys and values
    map.put(key, value);
    // Make the map unmodifiable, just in case
    map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

PS: if you're having a `Map<Integer, String>` which keys are consecutive (0,1,2,3,4...) then consider a `List<String>` instead because the list indexes perform the same goal as the keys in this case.

Comment: first of all- thanks!
and about the PS- I haven't decided yet whats going to be the key, the code is just for understanding the meaning.

Comment: @user4675862 Ok then, just keep that in mind :) I've updated my answer anyway with the static initializer.